# Sphinx searchd does not work when indexer is running

Tags: search, sphinx, indexer

I am using Sphinx 2.1.8.

Trying to index:
sudo -u sphinx indexer --rotate main_index

When indexer running, after a few minutes, searchd is stopping for a short time. Then it works again.

I tried to change mem_limit 64M, 128M, 256M and more combinations but nothing to be changed.

How can I run indexer with running searchd?

Answer (score 1):

That's kind of expected. The `--rotate` tells indexer, to instruct searchd to reload - so it can load the latest version of the index.

But it might be worthwhile looking at, 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-seamless-rotate
maybe can make it less noticable.